# How could I join row in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I create a datagridview with 5 columns :

```
Id   | SourceFileDate | ExcuteDate   | SourceFile | BackupFile

1    | 02/12/2015     |  02/12/2015  |C:\dak\hak  | E:\desktop\book 
2    | 03/12/2015     |  03/12/2015  |D:\dak\bak  | E:\desktop\book
```

- How could I join Column like this : 
  [Datagridview Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTcIH.png)
- My code connect database And I try to join, but not work :

  ```
  private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'backupDataSet5.TBLBackupFile' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
      //this.tBLBackupFileTableAdapter.Fill(this.backupDataSet5.TBLBackupFile);
      if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      {
          con.Close();
      }
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = "select (SourceFileDate+''+ExcuteDAte) as Date,(SourceFileName+''+DestinationFileName) as data from TBLBackupFile";
     // cmd.CommandText = "select * from TBLBackupFile";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      da.Fill(dt);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick for you

```
concat(column1, column2)
```

and thus your query would look like

```
select concat(SourceFileDate, ' ' ,ExcuteDAte) as Date,concat(SourceFileName, ' ' ,DestinationFileName) as data from TBLBackupFile
```

[CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) - Returns a string that is the result of concatenating two or more string values. CONCAT takes a variable number of string arguments and concatenates them into a single string. It requires a minimum of two input values; otherwise, an error is raised. All arguments are implicitly converted to string types and then concatenated. Null values are implicitly converted to an empty string. If all the arguments are null, an empty string of type varchar(1) is returned. The implicit conversion to strings follows the existing rules for data type conversions.

Comment: @ShrivastavaI It's run OK in Sql Server, but not run in datagridview.

Comment: How does you DGV looks like after running the query??

Comment: Yes this is what it is expected to do? What else you look for??

Comment: But It's not show to datagridview that I created in winform. How could I handle in code ?